# Clojure koans solution - But they are often better written using the names of functions

Tags: clojure

What has to be filled in the blanks for making is pass?

```
(= 25 (__ square))
```

This question is from clojure koans

Comment: http://clojurescriptkoans.com/#functions/10

Comment: What have *names of functions*  to do with it.

Comment: @Thumbnail - not sure I used the heading from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this is a stupid question to be present on Clojure Koans.  I don't recall anything this weird when I went through the Koans in 2014.

Here is the answer:

```
(fn [f] (f 5))  ; missing piece
```

You also need to know that the function `square` is `(fn [x] (* x x))` from the previous question.  They you have to define a (very dumb format) function as above and invoke it in place.  I have never seen anything like this horrible format in real life.

For the record, the entire answer will then look like:

```
(= 25 ( (fn [f] (f 5)) square))
```

where the previous problem #9 defines:

```
(defn square [n] (* n n))
```

---

P.S. If you haven't seen it yet, please check out these sites for Clojure documentation, examples, and reference:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/)
- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [Clojuredocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/)
- [Clojure-Doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/)
- [CrossClj.info](https://crossclj.info/)
- [CljDoc.org](https://cljdoc.org/)

Comment: The answer is not unique. For example, `(fn [_] 25)` will do.

Comment: @Thumbnail That will throw because you end up with `(= 25 (25 square))` and 25 is not a function.

Comment: @HendrikPoernama On my REPL, both `(= 25 ((fn [f] (f 5)) square))` and `(= 25 ((fn [_] 25) square))` evaluate to `true`. `((fn [_] 25) square)` evaluates to `25`, whatever `square` is. You can abbreviate it to `(constantly 25)`, which also works.

Comment: @Thumbnail You are correct. My mistake, I misinterpreted the code. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @HendrikPoernama Your confusion confirms that the point is worth making. So I've written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

We require a function that, applied to the function `square`, yields `25`. The answer [given by Alan Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564078/1562315) ...

```
(fn [f] (f 5))
```

... is the expected one. But there innumerable others. The simplest is the function that returnis 25, regardless of its argument:

```
(fn [_] 25)
```

This is a common enough construction that there is a core function [`constantly`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/constantly) to do it. So we can abbreviate the above to

```
(constantly 25)
```

We can convert any function capable of taking a single argument into a solution by overriding its response to the argument `square`:

```
(defn convert [g] (fn [x] (if (= x square) 25 (g x))))
```

For example,

```
=> ((convert +) square)
25
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the following high-order function:

```
#(% 5)
```

Which gives final solution as below?

```
(= 25 (#(% 5) square)))
```